# The cones for Bochner–Lichnerowicz–Weitzenböck formula

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

The Bochner–Lichnerowicz–Weitzenböck formula can be written the following way
$$ \Delta \phi-\nabla^*\nabla \phi= R(\phi),$$
here $\phi$ is a section in a Dirac bundle and $R$ the something which can be expressed in terms of its curvature.

One can get something nice applying this formula for different bundles associated to a given Riemannian manifols if $\langle R(\phi),\phi\rangle \ge 0$ for any $\phi$.

For the right choice of bundle, one gets $R$ to be Ricci curvature or scalar curvature and yet number of less popular curvatures.
Each of these conditions corresponds to a convex $O(n)$-invariant cone of curvature operators, let us call it *Weitzenböck cone*.

> **Question.** Is it well understood which cones are Weitzenböck and which are not?

For example assume I have a specific cone (say the cone $sec\ge 0$) is there someone who can tell that it is not a Weitzenböck cone.

Comment: When working on the bundle of $k$-forms, all of these cones contain the cone of nonnegative curvature operators (as operators on $2$-vectors). Can this be proved in general ?